# How to download SPE?

Tags: 13.10, python

How to download SPE in ubuntu 13.10.I have python2.7.6 in anaconda 1.8.0.I need it for making programs

Comment: Saisanjeev you should really stop flooding the system with questions on how to install python packages. Do your own research and ask if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** Go To Ubuntu Software Center.

**Step 2** Search SPE .

**Step 3** It Is At The Top Download It.

**Step 4**                    !!!Happy Programming!!![image: Ubuntu Software Center]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to open the Ubuntu Software Centre and to search for "SPE", and click install.